The tuning fails when using TargetTransfromer
I'm trying to perform target transformation for my three targets. It seems to be working but when I try to tune the model I get the "ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')." error. I don't know why this is happening.What I need to do is to perform power transformation on my target variables.
hyperparameters = {
    'regressor__estimator__n_estimators': [90,95,100,150, 200,300,400,500,600,800,1000,1200],
    'regressor__estimator__max_depth': [3,5,8,9,10,12,13,14, 15],
    'regressor__estimator__learning_rate': [0.01,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.35,0.4,0.5]
transformer = PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson')

start_time=time.time()
reg=XGBRegressor(random_state=42)
multioutput_regressor = MultiOutputRegressor(reg) 
# Create a TransformedTargetRegressor with the transformer
model = TransformedTargetRegressor(
    regressor=multioutput_regressor,  
    transformer=transformer,
    check_inverse=True
)


kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42) 
search = HalvingRandomSearchCV(model, hyperparameters, n_jobs=-1, cv=kf, random_state=42, error_score='raise')


# Train the model
search.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predictions on train and test sets
y_pred_train = search.predict(X_train)
y_pred = search.predict(X_test)

I tried checking my y_train using "y_trans=power_transform(y_train,method='yeo-johnson')". When I check the transformed targets, they seemed to be ok. They did't have any NAN or infinite values.I tried other transformations (quantile transformation and log transformation). Quantile works but it's not accurate enough. log transformaton doesn't work because I have zero values in my data. I also changed the tuning model to RandomizedSearchCV. It kept running with no success even for a very few iterations.One more thing that I did was setting "standardize" to false in powertransformation. It worked but the results weren't as good as the untuned model with standardize set to True.I tried doing a MinMaxScaling before powertransformation but it gave me the same error even though "standardize" was set to False in the power Transfromation.
